# How to access a column name in a user defined function with dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Here is my example df:

```
samp_df <- tibble(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
              var_in_df = c(3,7,9))
```

And here is an example of my function:

```
calculateMean <- function(df, variable){

     df <- df %>% 
     mutate(mean_of_var = mean({{variable}}))

}

df_result <- calculateMean(samp_df, var_in_df)
```

I want to be able to dynamically use the name of the column in the data frame when naming the new variable that is being created in the function and added to the data frame. For example, in the dataframe, the variable is titled `var_in_df`, and so in this example I would like my function to create a variable called "`mean_of_var_in_df`", I thought I could use a `paste` function, like this:

```
calculateMean <- function(df, variable){

  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(paste('mean_of', {{variable}}, sep = '-') = mean({{variable}}))

}
```

But that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do this? I also need to stick to the dplyr syntax, even though it might be easier with base R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the special assignment operator `:=` and making use of `glue` syntax you could do:

```r
samp_df <- tibble::tibble(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                  var_in_df = c(3,7,9))

library(dplyr)

calculateMean <- function(df, variable) {
  df %>%
    mutate("mean_of-{{variable}}" := mean({{ variable }}))
}

calculateMean(samp_df, var_in_df)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   var1  var_in_df `mean_of-var_in_df`
#>   <chr>     <dbl>               <dbl>
#> 1 a             3                6.33
#> 2 b             7                6.33
#> 3 c             9                6.33
```

Comment: Great. Just as a reference: See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#one-or-more-user-supplied-expressions for more info on this pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I ran into another related problem in the meantime, if you're curious you could also have a look :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74038698/dplyr-peform-operations-on-column-names-within-a-user-defined-function