# Peform operations on column names within a user defined function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I recently understood how to access a column names inside a user defined function: [How to access a column name in a user defined function with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74033167/how-to-access-a-column-name-in-a-user-defined-function-with-dplyr/74033231?noredirect=1#comment130725067_74033231)

However, now I also need to access the column names within the operations that are being carried out. For example I would like to do this:

```
samp_df <- tibble(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
              var_in_df = c(3,7,9))
calculateSummaries <- function(df, variable){
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate("mean_of_{{variable}}" := mean({{variable}}),
           "sd_of_{{variable}}" := sd({{variable}}),
           "sd_plus_mean_of_{{variable}}" := ("mean_of_{{variable}}" + "sd_of_{{variable}}")
           )
}
df_result <- calculateSummaries(samp_df, var_in_df)
```

Of course I could do:

```
"sd_plus_mean_of_{{variable}}" := mean({{variable}}) + sd({{variable}})
```

But in practice, with the real data this won't be practical.

Does anyone know how to so this?

Answer (score 3):

This case ineed a little bit tricky, I think we have to constuct the names first and then use `!! sym()` to evaluate the strings as objects.

```r
library(dplyr)

samp_df <- tibble(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                  var_in_df = c(3,7,9))

calculateSummaries <- function(df, variable){
  
  var_nm <- deparse(substitute(variable))
  
  mean_var_nm <- paste0("mean_of_", var_nm)
  sd_var_nm <- paste0("sd_of_", var_nm)
  
  df %>%
    mutate("mean_of_{{variable}}" := mean({{variable}}),
           "sd_of_{{variable}}" := sd({{variable}}),
           "sd_plus_mean_of_{{variable}}" := !! sym(mean_var_nm) + !! sym(sd_var_nm)
    )
}

calculateSummaries(samp_df, var_in_df)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   var1  var_in_df mean_of_var_in_df sd_of_var_in_df sd_plus_mean_of_var_in_df
#>   <chr>     <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>                     <dbl>
#> 1 a             3              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 2 b             7              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 3 c             9              6.33            3.06                      9.39
```

An alternative way is using `across()`, but we still have to construct the variable names.

```r
calculateSummaries <- function(df, variable){
  
  df %>%
    mutate("mean_of_{{variable}}" := mean({{variable}}),
           "sd_of_{{variable}}" := sd({{variable}}),
           across(c({{ variable }}),
                  list(sd_plus_mean_of = ~ get(paste0("mean_of_", cur_column())) + get(paste0("sd_of_", cur_column())))
                  )
    )
}

calculateSummaries(samp_df, var_in_df)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   var1  var_in_df mean_of_var_in_df sd_of_var_in_df var_in_df_sd_plus_mean_of
#>   <chr>     <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>                     <dbl>
#> 1 a             3              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 2 b             7              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 3 c             9              6.33            3.06                      9.39
```

Here is a final way inspired by Lionel Henry's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74051541/9349302). We can use `rlang::englue()` to construct names and use those names with the `.data[[...]]` pronoun.

```r
calculateSummaries <- function(df, variable){
  
  mean_var_nm <- rlang::englue("mean_of_{{ variable }}")
  sd_var_nm   <- rlang::englue("sd_of_{{ variable }}")
  
  df %>%
    mutate("mean_of_{{ variable }}" := mean({{ variable }}),
           "sd_of_{{ variable }}" := sd({{ variable }}),
           "sd_plus_mean_of_{{ variable }}" := .data[[mean_var_nm]] + .data[[sd_var_nm]]
    )
}

calculateSummaries(samp_df, var_in_df)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   var1  var_in_df mean_of_var_in_df sd_of_var_in_df sd_plus_mean_of_var_in_df
#>   <chr>     <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>                     <dbl>
#> 1 a             3              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 2 b             7              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 3 c             9              6.33            3.06                      9.39
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/#custom-result-names) tidyverse blog post glue strings are only supported as result names, which IMHO means only on the LHS.

Besides the options offered by @TimTeaFan another option would be to use `across` to compute all desired values and name the columns using the `.names` argument:

```r
library(dplyr)

calculateSummaries1 <- function(df, variable) {
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(across({{ variable }},
      .fns = list(
        mean = mean,
        sd = sd,
        sd_plus_mean = ~ mean(.x) + sd(.x)
      ),
      .names = "{.fn}_of_{.col}"
    ))
  df
}

calculateSummaries1(samp_df, var_in_df)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   var1  var_in_df mean_of_var_in_df sd_of_var_in_df sd_plus_mean_of_var_in_df
#>   <chr>     <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>                     <dbl>
#> 1 a             3              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 2 b             7              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 3 c             9              6.33            3.06                      9.39
```

And a second option would be to use some helper variable names for the mean and the sd which avoids to use glue syntax one the RHS but requires an additional `rename` step:

```
calculateSummaries2 <- function(df, variable) {
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(
      mean = mean({{ variable }}),
      sd = sd({{ variable }}),
      "sd_plus_mean_of_{{variable}}" := mean + sd
    ) |>
    rename("mean_of_{{variable}}" := mean, "sd_of_{{variable}}" := sd)

  df
}
calculateSummaries2(samp_df, var_in_df)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   var1  var_in_df mean_of_var_in_df sd_of_var_in_df sd_plus_mean_of_var_in_df
#>   <chr>     <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>                     <dbl>
#> 1 a             3              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 2 b             7              6.33            3.06                      9.39
#> 3 c             9              6.33            3.06                      9.39
```